# Android Studio not importing project files

Tags: android, android-studio

I work on two different PCs with Android Studio. The workspace is shared. I did the same with eclipse and never ran into any problems.

Anyway, I just imported an Android Studio project into my home PC. It is refusing to import any of the app files (java classes, xmls etc). I can see the files in the folder on my PC but it refuses to import them. The app folder is basically empty.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: how did you import the project? I understand the folder is shared accross PCs, so you should be able to just open the project?

Comment: Import Android Studio Project (since it already has the gradle files and structure). I created this project a couple of days ago in my office Android Studio so it should work fine here too.

Comment: okay, but what about just opening it instead of importing?

Comment: Same result. For the time being, I've just recreated the project and copied in the files.